# Репозитории и сервисы при проектировании по DDD

Tags: php, веб-программирование, проектирование, ddd

Теоретический вопрос по DDD. Есть сущности: Article, Comment. Они являются частью одного агрегата Article, где корневой сущностью является Article.

Так как корнем является Article и Comment ей принадлежит, то репозиторий и сервисы создаются только для Article? Но не будет ли нарушен принцип единой ответственности, ведь в них будет теперь и работы с комментариями? Да и объем классов будет выше, и это всего две сущности в Агрегате.

К тому же, комментарии могут быть и у сущности Видео, например, уже в составе другого агрегата. Тогда добавление комментария будет и в сервисе статьи, и в сервисе  видео. Как-то не верно... Или верно?

Comment: Вы слишком жёстко понимаете принцип единой ответственности :) Это же не запрет на любые числительные, кроме "один". Если понимать его так, то у вас в агрегате две сущности - и значит вы нарушаете S.

Comment: Я могу понимать по разному: как правильно, так и не правильно, так и просто по другому. Но как понимает большинство, и какой ответ на вопрос по их мнению ? :)

Comment: Причем тут большинство? Это же конкретный принцип и конкретное решение в вашем проекте. Если вы можете сформулировать ту самую единственну причину, по которой ArticleRepo меняется - хотя бы в виде "сущности корня Article стали сохраняться в Storage по-другому" - с SRP все ок. Если при при формулировке получаются всегда несколько разных/независимых c точки зрения предметной области (ну или акторов) причин для изменения - то не ок. Если совсем уж строго - SRP вообще исключительно для "причин с точки зрения людей-акторов" сформулирован, и разбиение репозиториев вообще никак не покрывает :)

Comment: Почитайте определение responsibility / reason to change от автора: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html - "the reasons for change are people"

Comment: Не владею терминами (DDD, responsibility), но мое мнение таково: Article не нужны комментарии, чтобы существовать. Комментарии - отдельная весчь, такая же как просмотры, рейтинги и тд, что только может быть присоединено. Плюс комментарии могут быть привязаны не только к Article, но и к Section или еще куданибудь. Поэтому для них я бы сделал отдельный репозиторий. А вот уже кто-нибудь ответственный за определенный сценарий будет отдельно запрашивать массив (или не массив) Article и отдельно комментарии

Comment: @Skywave возможно вы правы. Есть такое правило, если entity находится в разных агрегатах, тогда оно само должно быть агрегатом.  А комментарии могут быть у видео, у статьи, у еще чего нить, но опять таки зависит от проекта. Стоит ли сразу делать комментарии агрегатом с своим репозиторием или нет - уже немного другой вопрос.

Comment: Прежде всего DDD, ничего не говорит о SRP, поэтому можете не накладывать на себя дополнительные ограничения). Во вторых, необходимость создания агрегата возникает из требований к консистентности. К примеру, если статья хочет иметь у себя счетчик комментариев, то очевидно не очень то правильно управлять комментариями в отрыве от статьи и тогда удобно размещать в общем агрегате.